# Curl Bad Request 400 on curl to docker server container

Tags: cleos, nodeos

I am trying to make calls to EOS nodeos server inside a docker container from the host machine.

Although the port 7777 is exposed:

```
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
e447cb3d2db5        eosio/eos           "/bin/bash"              3 days ago          Up 3 days           0.0.0.0:7777->7777/tcp   server
```

When making the curl request, I get a 400 Bad Request error.

```
$ curl -vv -X POST http://127.0.0.1:7777/v1/chain/get_info
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) port 7777 (#0)
> POST /v1/chain/get_info HTTP/1.1
> Host: 127.0.0.1:7777
> User-Agent: curl/7.47.0
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
```

the docker network is:

```
$ docker network ls
NETWORK ID          NAME                DRIVER              SCOPE
d3d275c83226        bridge              bridge              local
9f6a5439c22c        eosnetwork          bridge              local
db156b84ea13        host                host                local
83e9116a4419        none                null                local
```

Any idea why it is happening and how to fix it?

## UPDATE

curl to the ip of the container works:

```
$ curl  -X POST http://172.18.0.2:7777/v1/chain/get_info
{"server_version":"08819aae","chain_id":"aca376f206b8fc25a6ed44dbdc66547c36c6c33e3a119ffbeaef943642f0e906","head_block_num":8085665,"last_irreversible_block_num":8085335,"last_irreversible_block_id":"007b5f5749c6dd4f268adc7e93597d0d6e0f8a6e2f04ec3f7b6c45e292ecac0f","head_block_id":"007b60a1e043ecee30589a74540ef241a287f16a0610b6d2fa33421adefe366a","head_block_time":"2018-07-27T19:08:14.500","head_block_producer":"eos42freedom","virtual_block_cpu_limit":200000000,"virtual_block_net_limit":1048576000,"block_cpu_limit":200000,"block_net_limit":1048576,"server_version_string":"v1.2.5"}
```

but I need it to work on from 127.0.0.1. Anyway to achieve that?

Answer (score 2):

After two days of trials and errors, I finally made it work.

To access the nodeos from another machine we need to do two things:

1. start the docker where the nodeos is running with "docker run --net=host" option
2. start the nodeos with "--http-validate-host=false" option

I hope it helps someone in the future!

Answer (score 0):

This is the tutorial for the docker image: https://developers.eos.io/eosio-nodeos/docs/docker-quickstart

According to the docker documentation (https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/), you need to add published port flag like `-p 8888:8888` to your docker command. This will map the TCP port 8888 of the container to the TCP port 8888 of the Docker host.

`--http-validate-host=false` is needed as well in your nodeos `config.ini`.